# Should prospective husband and wife have mutually compatible names?

Tags: marriage, name, wife, husband

Without having to hurt or offend any sentiments, I would like to know if the names of prospective husband and wife are taken in account before marriage.

What if the names are incompatible from the divine point of view?

For example, if prospective Husband's name is Shiva or Rudra, and the prospective wife's name is Saraswati. Then should this kind of marriage be happening or name changes are to be made. Because Saraswati, the goddess - is already wife of Lord Brahma ji, while Shiv ji has wife Parvati mata.

Are such incompatibility arising out from clashes due to divine godly couple's names an impediment?

Comment: At least Manu Smriti is silent on incompatible names iirc.